# Add dashes only before and after each group of odd digits

Tags: javascript

I Need to add dashes only before and after each group of odd digits.
I am trying this, but this does not work so good:

```
function addDashes(num) {
    return num.toString().
      replace(/([13579])/g,'-$1-'). // dashes around odd digits
      replace(/\-+/g,'-'). // replace multiple dashes by one dash
      replace(/^\-/,''). // remove starting dash
      replace(/\-$/,''); // remove ending dash
}
```

I got this:

```
console.log(addDashes(645545965)); // '64-5-5-4-5-9-6-5'
console.log(addDashes(411222333)); // '4-1-1-222-3-3-3'
console.log(addDashes(81229576231)); // '8-1-22-9-5-7-62-3-1'
```

But I need this:

```
console.log(addDashes(645545965)); // '64-55-4-59-6-5'
console.log(addDashes(411222333)); // '4-11-222-333'
console.log(addDashes(81229576231)); // '8-1-22-957-62-31'
```

Comment: I think this question is not very appropriate for StackOverflow. This is more for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @rsmeral In the current form this question would be _off-topic_ for code review because that site is for reviewing **working** code. Please read about what is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that site before recommending users post there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done everything right instead of repeated one

```
([13579]+)
```

I mean if you've two number from `13579` more than one time then you just consider it a group and add `-` around the group.

```js
function addDashes(num) {
  return num
    .toString()
    .replace(/([13579]+)/g, "-$1-") // dashes around odd digits
    .replace(/\-+/g, "-") // replace multiple dashes by one dash
    .replace(/^\-/, "") // remove starting dash
    .replace(/\-$/, ""); // remove ending dash
}

console.log(addDashes(645545965)); 
console.log(addDashes(411222333)); 
console.log(addDashes(81229576231));
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how to get this through `reduce`, so here's that method.

```js
function addDashes(num) {
  return (''+num).split('').reduce((acc, n) => {
      let len = acc.length, p = +acc[len - 1];
      if (len == 0) return [n]; else if (n%2 + p%2 != 1) acc[len - 1] += n; else acc.push(n);
      return acc
    }, []).join("-");
}

console.log(addDashes(645545965));
console.log(addDashes(411222333));
console.log(addDashes(81229576231));
```